# Incorrect timestamp min / max

Tags: mysql, database, aggregate-functions

I have a report that I need to show the first visit and the latest visit of clients. I am relaying heavily on mysql DATE_FORMAT functions and feel fairly confident with my use of that function. However I am noticing an anomaly that I can not quite grasp.

My report :

```
    +-----------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
    | A-Number  | First     | Last       | Total | First Visit         | Latest Visit        |
    +-----------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
    | xxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxx  | xxxxxxx    |     3 | Jun 04, 2013 - 3PM  | May 29, 2013 - 3PM  |
    | xxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxx   | xxxxxxxx   |     2 | May 15, 2013 - 12PM | May 28, 2013 - 9AM  |
    | xxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxx   | xxxxxxxxx  |     2 | Jun 03, 2013 - 1PM  | May 28, 2013 - 4PM  |
    | xxxxxxxxx | xxxxxx    | xxxxxx     |     1 | Apr 24, 2013 - 7PM  | Apr 24, 2013 - 7PM  |
    +-----------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

This is actual data. I have around 1100+ students who currently use this system and I need to report on when they come in and what not. If you notice the first row the first visit is June 04? but the latest visit is may 29??

The next issue is the second row (this works how it is supposed to) notice may 15 -> first visit, then may 28th latest visit. (this is good).

Is there a problem with the different key words in the month name? May / Jun?

I am really confused with this.

This is my query :

```
        SELECT
            DATE_FORMAT(signintime, '%W %Y') Date,
            student.anum 'A-Number',
            student.first 'First',
            student.last 'Last',
            COUNT(session.anum) as Total,
            MIN(DATE_FORMAT(session.signintime, '%b %d, %Y - %l%p')) as 'First Visit',
            MAX(DATE_FORMAT(session.signintime, '%b %d, %Y - %l%p')) as 'Lastest Visit'
        FROM student
            INNER JOIN session
            ON session.anum = student.anum
        GROUP BY student.anum
        ORDER BY Total desc;
```

Edit 1 :

Fix as pointed out by piotrm :

```
SELECT 
    student.anum 'A-Number', 
    student.first First, 
    student.last Last, 
    COUNT(session.anum) Total, 
    DATE_FORMAT(MIN(session.signintime), '%b %d, %Y - %l%p') 'First Visit',    
    DATE_FORMAT(MAX(session.signintime), '%b %d, %Y - %l%p') 'Latest Visit' 
FROM student 
    INNER JOIN session 
        ON session.anum = student.anum GROUP BY student.anum;
```

Comment: DATE_FORMAT returns a string so it is sorted alphabetically (according to collation used). Why don't you use DATE_FORMAT(MIN(session.signintime), ... )?

Comment: Wow you really did just save my ass here @piotrm.

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` usage is incorrect and will be rejected by every DBMS except MySQL. MySQL doesn't bother telling you it's incorrect and simply returns random data if `GROUP BY` in that case. Read the following to understand why: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html and http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: This is true, however for this particular query (the fixed one, not the first one) all columns are fine as all student.* values are the same within each group. So you will get a random out of all equal values. You could just put correct syntax `GROUP BY s.anum,s.first,s.last` for the same result. Having no need to put all these columns in the GROUP BY is the very reason mysql allows this type of syntax.